# Satori is not initialized: expect yoga to be loaded, got undefined #301

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, tsx

Steps to reproduce this error:

Download or clone this [Satori](https://github.com/vercel/satori) example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cover-image-bf6282?from-embed=&file=/src/index.tsx

Run the example (`npm start`) and press the Download button in the launched page.

You'll get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Satori is not initialized: expect `yoga` to be loaded, got undefined

What could be the problem, and how to fix it?

I think the problem is here:

**svg-utils.ts:**

```
export const svgToPngURL = (svg: string) =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
      canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx!.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    };
    img.onerror = (e) => {
      reject(e);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svg], { type: "image/svg+xml" }));
  });

export const downloadSvgAsPng = async (svg: string) => {
  const pngURL = await svgToPngURL(svg);
  try {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = pngURL;
    a.download = "Image.png";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  } finally {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(pngURL);
  }
};
```